# Is there a way to do string removing in html tags?

Tags: python, html, css, flask, jinja2

```
{% for term in terms %}
     <div class="term term-count-{{loop.index}}">
        <b>{{ term }}</b>: &nbsp;&nbsp; {{ terms[term] }} &nbsp;&nbsp;
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

'terms' is a dictionary with the value as a list in Python:

```
terms = {'a':['1','2','3'], 'b':['4','5','6'], 'c': ['x', 'y', 'z']}
```

The current html code will display the 'terms' as follows in the for loop:

```
a: ['1','2','3']
b: ['4','5','6']
c: ['x', 'y', 'z']
```

I want the quotes to be removed as follows:

```
a: [1, 2, 3]
b: [4, 5, 6]
c: [x, y, z]
```

Is there a way to run a string removing function in the html blocks? If not, is there other possible ways to display as I expected? This is in a Flask project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your html to

```
{% for key, value in terms.items() %}
     <div class="term term-count-{{loop.index}}">
        <b>{{ key }}</b>: &nbsp;&nbsp; [{{ value|join(', ') }}] &nbsp;&nbsp;
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

it will render to:

```
 <div class="term term-count-1">
    <b>a</b>: &nbsp;&nbsp; [1, 2, 3] &nbsp;&nbsp;
 </div>

 <div class="term term-count-2">
    <b>b</b>: &nbsp;&nbsp; [4, 5, 6] &nbsp;&nbsp;
 </div>

 <div class="term term-count-3">
    <b>c</b>: &nbsp;&nbsp; [x, y, z] &nbsp;&nbsp;
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show without the '', you will need to show this as an element of the list.

```
  a = ['1','2']
  So you will need to do like
  <h1>
  {{a[0]}}
  </h1>
```

Or you can do something like below. It is not the best way but this does work to remove the ''. From the list, the code is:

https://github.com/Programmer-RD-AI/Stackoverflow-Questions/tree/main/Is%20there%20a%20way%20to%20do%20string%20removing%20in%20html%20tags%3F

Check the above link. You can get the code from there.